# Why apt-get is unable to locate jigdo-file or jigdo-lite?

Tags: debian, apt

There is something I'm not getting right with the debian package system, I'm pretty confident that the jigdo program is contained in the Debian repository system (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jigdo&searchon=names&suite=jessie&section=all) yet when I try `apt-get install jigdo-file` it says `unable to locate jigdo-file package`.

My source.list is :

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20160123-19:00]/ jessie main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20160123-19:00]/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.

# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

I do `apt-get update` clean whatever and it still won't find it. What am I missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sources.list seems to have jessie-updates (previously known as "volatile") and jessie security, but you're missing the normal jessie sources.

Adding:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

and doing `apt-get update` ought to fix it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that jessie-update wasn't ought to be I thought it was the main thing, do you know what's thedifference between those two ? Thanks ?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs jessie-updates only contains a few packages that need to be updated outside the stable release cycle (e.g., clamav, time zone data). You can see a list at https://packages.debian.org/jessie-updates/

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210394/what-is-the-difference-between-the-jessie-and-jessie-updates-distributions-i for more details.