# What are the security implications of omitting the 'security.debian.org' sources from sources.list in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, security, apt, upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading a standalone dual quad-core Xeon PowerEdge rack server from Wheezy to Jessie. In following the debian.org [instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) for the upgrade, only the following `deb` line is mentioned as needing to be placed into `sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian jessie main contrib
```

In this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210394/what-is-the-difference-between-the-jessie-and-jessie-updates-distributions-i) and answer, I learned that the `jessie/updates` source on `security.debian.org` supplies "Security-critical updates ... provid[ing] the safest fix for security issues as quickly as possible.... These updates are usually merged into the next stable update."

I use the server for quantum chemical computations; its only (intentional) inbound interactions from the outside world are when I SSH into a console, through NAT via an SSH port opened in and redirected by my router. `root` login is disabled, and I have [`denyhosts`](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) installed and configured to parse `auth.login` every thirty seconds in order to clamp down on hack attempts.

I do have `gdm` installed, and browse the web occasionally with Firefox (GitHub, StackExchange, Gmail, Twitter, etc.). I also pull from and push to GitHub repos from time to time.

**So: What are the security implications of omitting the `security.debian.org jessie/updates` sources from my `sources.list`?** (To note, I see no reason ***not*** to include them; I'm just curious whether leaving them out would represent a major security problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will miss important security updates. `ssh` had few security updates recently, you will miss also updates to firewall (not so needed under NAT, but you should also not trust so much our local network).

I think in the past security was used also to patch a `ntp` bug (which hanged computers on leap second).

And you should not forget about outgoing connections. Also that should be secure: e.g. injection and downgrading could make you download unwanted data/virus, or some program disclose too much information. So check also about outbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just curious whether leaving them out would represent a major security problem.

Well it would. When a security hole becomes public, you need to install the patched code or you will be a sitting duck.

Your other security measures might be useful, but only in conjunction with software that has been patched for known vulnerabilities.