# Why can't APT find package?

Tags: debian, apt

I have a new install of Debian 8 ("Jessie") and want to install the `firewalld` package, but APT can't find it. This may be related to the fact that I didn't specify a mirror during installation, but as far as I can tell, I've made the appropriate configurations.

`firewalld` is located on the mirror here:

`http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/firewalld/`

That mirror is in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
```

I've updated the available packages:

`# apt update`

APT still can't find it:

```
# apt search firewalld
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Why can't it find the package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the full Jessie repository in your `sources.list`; you should have at least

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
```

(you can add `contrib` if you want, and the corresponding `deb-src` lines if you want to be able to download source code for the packages too).

Check your `sources.list` contains at least those three lines, then run

```
apt update
apt install firewalld
```

The `jessie-updates` repository only contains updates to Jessie, it doesn’t contain the packages which were part of the original Jessie release and haven't been updated since. See [What is the difference between the "jessie" and "jessie-updates" distributions in /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210394/86440) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

"Installing firewalld package on Debian 8 (Jessie) is as easy as running the following command on terminal:"

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install firewalld

From https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/debian/jessie/firewalld

Comment: I see my answer was downvoted. I take it that means that website has bad advice. :-)

Comment: No, it means you're not addressing the problem that the OP has.

Comment: @StephenKitt Your point is well-taken. It looks like you know more about this than I do.

Comment: Appearances can be deceptive ;-). Welcome to Unix.SE, I hope this doesn’t put you off — I’m sure you’ll have plenty of opportunities to answer questions!