# How to install software-properties-common in Debian 9

Tags: debian

I am stuck with this :-

```
# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Here is the output of apt-cache policy

```
apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 release a=now
1000 http://downloads.mariadb.com/Tools/debian stretch/main amd64   Packages
 release o=MariaDB Enterprise,n=stretch,l=MariaDB,c=main,b=amd64
 origin downloads.mariadb.com
1000 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MaxScale/2.3/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 release o=MariaDB,n=stretch,l=MariaDB Maxscale repository,c=main,b=amd64
 origin downloads.mariadb.com
1000 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.3/repo/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 release o=MariaDB,n=stretch,l=MariaDB,c=main,b=amd64
 origin downloads.mariadb.com
 500 http://mariadb.nethub.com.hk/repo/10.3/debian stretch/main ppc64el Packages
 release o=MariaDB,n=stretch,l=MariaDB,c=main,b=ppc64el
 origin mariadb.nethub.com.hk
 500 http://mariadb.nethub.com.hk/repo/10.3/debian stretch/main i386  Packages
 release o=MariaDB,n=stretch,l=MariaDB,c=main,b=i386
 origin mariadb.nethub.com.hk
 500 http://mariadb.nethub.com.hk/repo/10.3/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 release o=MariaDB,n=stretch,l=MariaDB,c=main,b=amd64
 origin mariadb.nethub.com.hk
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
 release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
 origin security.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Answer (score 2):

Your repository configuration doesn’t include the Debian 9 repositories (apart from the security repository); you need to ensure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains at least

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
```

Comment: Ok and thank you. What is the precise difference between stretch, stretch-updates, and stretch/updates ? Can you please explain?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210405/86440), the rules for Stretch are the same as for Jessie in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Since [package `software-properties-common` definitely exists in Debian 9](https://packages.debian.org/stable/software-properties-common), the problem must be in the repository mirror you're using.

Try using a different repository.